# Jest test files that import typescript modules have to `require` and then use the `default` key

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, es6-modules

I'm running a test file that imports a typescript module, and as such the `test.js` file looks something like:

```
// typescript-module.ts
const fn = (): void => false;

export default fn
```

```js
const module = require("./typescript-module");
```

The only problem I seem to have is that I don't automatically get the `default` export assigned via commonjs? I have access to an object with the shape `{ default : ..., __esmodule: true}` which tells me that... it hasn't been parsed into commonjs properly?

I obviously can get it working if I just `const module = require("./typescript-module").default` but that just feels... real messy and unsanctioned to me.

My `.tsconfig` has `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` set to `true`, and `esModuleInterop` is `true` also.

I'm using `ts-jest` for transforming `ts` files for tests in my `jest.config.js`. I'm just wondering if there's something I'm missing

I want to be able to `require` my `ts` modules default exports, but I'm just not sure what part of the toolchain controls that.

If you need any more information, please let me know!